# Remote desktop drive redirection: get underlying location of client's redirected drives

Tags: rds, mappeddrive

Users can use local devices (in this case drives) in their remote desktop session. These show up as `\\tsclient\drivelettter` redirected drives when doing `net use` in RD session.

[net use example showing shared drives in RD session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6mlo.png)

Let's consider one such redirected drive, `\\tsclient\H`. Is there any way to know whether this points to a resource truly on the client's computer (a piece of hardware, like an internal or external SSD, a USB, ... → "\\ClientMachine\ExternalDiskH") versus a redirected drive itself (→ "\\RemoteFileServer\ShareName") ? I'd like to know the "underlying location", so to speak, which the expression `\\tsclient\H` points to.

**Use Case**

Laptop (ClientMachine) has mapped drive pointing to their home directory on OurFileServer. If RD connection is established, drives are available in their session as redirected. But the mapped drives are also redirected, which can result in needless bandwith use: from OurFileServer to ClientMachine and back to RemoteDesktopServer. ClientMachine may be far away, used by person working from home. It would be better to identify that `\\tsclient\H` is in fact pointing to `\\OurFileServer\PathToHomeDirectory` and decide to not redirect the drive in that case. Then, the user will never use the roundabout back-and-forth way to access files from his home directory. Distance between OurFileServer and RemoteDesktopServer is much shorter (on site). However, if `\\tsclient\H` is a local resource to ClientMachine, say a USB drive or an external harddrive, then we do want to make it available in the RDS session.

Comment: The Remote Desktop API provides access to a limited amount of information of the remote device. Device name, IP address, and client version is about it.

Comment: Do you want to query it from the RDS servers or in a session of a user? Not sure what your use case is and why you want to see it, but with group policy you can control which drives can be redirected

Comment: I'd like to know it with Powershell while user is logging on. Use case is that we don't want ClientMachine to have a redirected disk pointing to \\OurFileServer\PathToUserHomeFolder and then redirect that again to the RD session. Because then, traffic could go from OurFileServer to ClientMachine and back to OurRDServer.

Comment: @Turdie. I added a use case to my question.